# Call TYPO3 plugin from other plugin's body by cObject

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I've injected plugin in the template to display specific data from the controller and it works fine. But now I have to make an AJAX call to receive some records based on the select filter from this specific plugin. I wanted to inject second plugin into this first plugin to the template to make a possibility to return data as a partial template to the frontend.

This is a typoscript file:

```
lib.firstPlugin =< tt_content.list.20.first_p
```

In the template I use cObject to render this first plugin:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.firstPlugin"/>
```

It is even possible? How I can send AJAX call to receive only partial template from the backend (in this case some records) to the first plugin. I used similar code as above for the second plugin and it doesn't work (AJAX call will always go to the first plugin and default controller method).

Thank you for potential tips.

Comment: Why not using Middleware? https://usetypo3.com/psr15-middleware-in-typo3.html

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea with middleware, thanks.

I have a new idea: maybe I should create a new page type which will contain plugin for AJAX responses in the new template? In general the whole template should be empty by default in this case? Of course to the URL I have to attach this typeNum.

Overall I think it should work? Is it a good approach?

Comment: Your TypoScript setup is possible, you just have to take care perhaps that definitions are in the correct order, so that required code-dependencies are known when used / copied. You also can copy the code like in your question and afterwards add or overwrite single properties in the copy, even remove undesired ones with `undesiredProperty >`. This solution is flexible and less work than a middleware.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already solved this by new plugin with default empty templates :)